# Tornado ThreadPoolExecutor delays requests when yielding results

Tags: python, tornado, threadpoolexecutor

**System specification**
 - MacOS 10.13.6 
 - Python 3.7.0
 - Tornado 5.1.1

I'd like to use a ThreadPoolExecutor to run blocking functions
in a Tornado instance that serves a RESTful service.

The ThreadPool works as expected and spawns four worker threads in parallel (see code and console log below) as long as I am not trying to yield results returned by the executed function.

**ThreadPoolExecutor without yielding results**

```
import time
import tornado.web
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

MAX_WORKERS = 4
i = 0

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)

    @run_on_executor
    def background_task(self, i):
        print("going sleep %s" % (i))
        time.sleep(10);
        print("waking up from sleep %s" % (i))
        return str(i)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        global i
        i+=1
        self.background_task(i)


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0')
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

**Console output**

```
going sleep 1
going sleep 2
going sleep 3
going sleep 4
waking up from sleep 1
going sleep 5
waking up from sleep 2
going sleep 6
waking up from sleep 3
going sleep 7
waking up from sleep 4
going sleep 8
waking up from sleep 5
going sleep 9
waking up from sleep 6
waking up from sleep 7
waking up from sleep 8
waking up from sleep 9
```

As can be seen, four parallel workers are running, and as soon as one finishes, a queued function is being executed.

However, I have some issues when I try to yield return functions using a coroutine. While it does not fully block the IoLoop, it gets delayed without a clear pattern.

**Altered code: ThreadPoolExecutor now yielding result**

```
MAX_WORKERS = 4
i = 0

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)

    @run_on_executor
    def background_task(self, i):
        print("%s: Going sleep %s" % (time.time(), i))
        time.sleep(10);
        print("%s: Waiking up from sleep %s" % (time.time(), i))
        return str(i)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        global i
        i+=1
        result = yield self.background_task(i)
        self.write(result)
```

Looking at the console output, only a single thread runs for the 1st and 2nd request, executing the queueing tasks once the single thread is finished (causing a delay of 10seconds to start task 2 and another to start task 3). However, task 3,4,5 and 6 are executed in parallel but with varying delays between each call.

**Console output**

```
1548687401.331075: Going sleep 1
1548687411.333173: Waking up from sleep 1
1548687411.340162: Going sleep 2
1548687421.3419871: Waking up from sleep 2
1548687421.347039: Going sleep 3
1548687423.4030259: Going sleep 4
1548687423.884313: Going sleep 5
1548687424.6828501: Going sleep 6
1548687431.351986: Waking up from sleep 3
1548687431.3525162: Going sleep 7
1548687433.407232: Waking up from sleep 4
1548687433.407604: Going sleep 8
1548687433.8846452: Waking up from sleep 5
1548687433.885139: Going sleep 9
1548687434.685195: Waking up from sleep 6
1548687434.685662: Going sleep 10
1548687441.3577092: Waking up from sleep 7
1548687441.358009: Going sleep 11
1548687443.412503: Waking up from sleep 8
1548687443.888705: Waking up from sleep 9
1548687444.691127: Waking up from sleep 10
1548687451.359714: Waking up from sleep 11
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Do you have any fix?

Comment: How are you generating your requests? If you're using browser tabs you may be running into http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#my-code-is-asynchronous-but-it-s-not-running-in-parallel-in-two-browser-tabs

Comment: Hi @BenDarnell, thank you for the pointer. In fact I tried it with multiple tabs, with Postman and with ionic instances running in my browser. All had the issues described in the docs that I must have missed. It works as expected. If you answer I"ll mark your comment as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Python Tornado memory leaks when using ThreadPoolExecutor, so Tornado is not usable.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the configuration of the CPU and workload, the process split the task. We can verify with simple start chrome options to test concurrency.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).